# Add user to group after post_save signal

Tags: python, django

I want to add a user to a group after the user object is saved. Each user has a `permission level` corresponding to the group the user belongs to. For example, if the `permission level` is `3`, then the user belongs to `Group_3`, and so on.

This is my code:

`models.py`

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    ID = models.IntegerField(default=random_integer, unique=True)
    permissions = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name


def add_2_group(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        if instance.permissions == 3:
            group = Group.objects.get(name='Group_3')  
            group.user_set.add(instance)

post_save.connect(add_2_group, sender=User)
```

As you can see, I am using a `post_save` signal to add the user to the group after saving the user instance. However, this is not working. Apparently, nothing happens after saving the user. How do I solve this?

---

EDIT:

I understood where the problem was: the default `permission level` is set to `0`, and I was only checking for a `permission level` of `3`. However, now I am facing another strange problem. This is the change I made to the code:

```
def add_2_group(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        if instance.permissions == 0:     
            group = Group.objects.get(name='Group_0')  
            instance.groups.add(group)

    else:
        if instance.permissions == 3:   
            group = Group.objects.get(name='Group_3')            
            instance.groups.add(group)
```

Basically, when I save the user model with a `permission level` of `3`, the group does not get updated. Thus, the user always stays on `Group_0`, and does not become part of `Group_3`. It seems that `instance.groups.add(group)` does not work when saving the user; it works only when creating it. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: you could just save the user on creation.

Comment: That's true, but I want to give the admin a chance to update the permission level in case he/she needs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the problem, I had to remove the `groups` field from the `fieldsets` in `admin.py`, as it would prevent the instance from being added to the group.